# hide partial value from select option

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking to hide a partial value from a option menu :
the value [DB-2676] should hide it by changing its color to white if that makes sense. all values on the option menu are listed as {2 letter} - {4 numbers}.
don't know how to use regular expression to select only a partial value from text string.

[image]

```
<select name="seletion2" class="form-control">
  <option value="size 24x24x54>color>red> CP-2376">size 24x24x54&gt;color&gt;red&gt; DB-2376</option>
  <option value="size 24x24x54>color>red> CP-2376">size 24x24x54&gt;color&gt;red&gt; DB-2522</option>
</select>
```

Comment: isn't that last 7 characters? ... as in the 2 samples options

Comment: Why does the DB-2376 need to be displayed to the user and not just obmitted when generating the select box?

ie:
<option value="123">My value 123</option>
becomes
<option value="123">My value</option>

In which case a trim would be used to obmit it from the backend language used

Comment: good thought. we need to have that value passed to cart to specific usage. we  just want to hide it from the user so they don't get confused!

Comment: @David - I don't think you understand what DataCure was telling you. The value that is passed to the cart comes from the `value` property of the `Option` element and not from the string the user sees. Please re-read DataCure's comment and ask questions about that response.

Comment: So basically instead of hiding it, try to not display it at all when generating the <select> element.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Here is a solution which will edit the values of each OPTION that contains the attribute amendValue="true", otherwise it will ignore it.

I am a bit confused as to why this isnt taken care of in the backend language that generates the drop down:

PHP Example:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $myVal . "\">".$myVal."</option>";
```

would become something like

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $myVal . "\">". substr($myVal, strlen($myVal)-7)."</option>";
```

Which would give you the same HTML output you are seeking:

```
<option value="size 24x24x54>color>red> CP-2376">size 24x24x54>color>red></option>
```

However as you have asked how this is done using JavaScript, I have done a short script for you that demonstrates it working, I have added an attribute called "amendValue" this is only to differentiate it from other option elements, otherwise it will trim every `<option>` displayed on the webpage

```js
var intCharactersToDelete = 7;
function funStart(){
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  for (x = 0; x < el.length; x++){
    var AttAmend = el[x].getAttribute("amendValue");
    if (AttAmend == "true"){
      var strValue = el[x].innerHTML;
      strValue=strValue.substring(0,(el[x].innerHTML.length  - intCharactersToDelete));
      console.log(strValue);
       el[x].innerHTML = strValue;
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funStart,false);
```

```html
<select name="seletion2" class="form-control">
  <option amendValue="true" value="size 24x24x54>color>red> CP-2376">size 24x24x54&gt;color&gt;red&gt; DB-2376</option>
  <option amendValue="true" value="size 24x24x54>color>red> CP-2376">size 24x24x54&gt;color&gt;red&gt; DB-2522</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cough.. Please, Dont forget to rate the answer 

Comment: I want to hide part of the value inside autocomplete option, guess, this solution won't work? Cause part of the text will be completely removed, and autocomplete won't be able to match hidden string